# Is "theme" global object available in all files in Material-ui?

Tags: material-ui

I have been following [Material-UI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_AN49fA9g0&list=PLQg6GaokU5CwiVmsZ0d_9Zsg_DnIP_xwr&index=3) tutorial to learn Material-UI. At 9:25 it passes "theme" to makeStyles function. My question is "How is theme object's values are available there just so? such that they can be accessed in the subsequent body like theme.breakpoints.down("sm") for example.That "theme" is not defined so far in the file.  I tried reading the documentation and it mentions nothing about it quite right. [makestyles documentation](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook).Can somebody explain to me what is happening there?

Answer (score 1):

**Material UI** has a function called `createMuiTheme` and the main purpose of it, is to create a `muiTheme`, deep merging *defaults* with *user custom theme options* and store it in `defaultTheme` constant https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/styles/defaultTheme.js

and in `makeStyles` function it simply import that `defaultTheme` https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/styles/makeStyles.js

hope this would be helpful

Comment: Thanks. A little question though. So, it should have been `makeStyles(defaultTheme => { color: defaultTheme.palette.common.main }` instead of` makeStyles(theme => { color: theme.palette.common.main }`.Right? How does just referencing "theme" points to defaultTheme in later case?. The question might be silly. But I am a beginner. So it would help if you could point some other good resources to understand.

Comment: no, not really, both of  these 2 codes are right because `makeStyles` would fill that variant and you can name it whatever you want. its just naming and `makeStyles` will fill it for you.